# Set default value for district / Allow one district

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, default

I'm living in Bangladesh where the state not available. the woocommerce state change to district that's why I cant able to place default value for that .. can anyone help me with a code to set the default value for the district

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not related with coding.

Comment: why its off topic?

Answer (score 0):

**Please must br try it this code:**

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_state', 'your_default_checkout_state' );

function your_default_checkout_state() {
  return 'BANGLADESH'; // state code
}
```

Comment: i want to set the default for district called "Gazipur".. what should i do?